# How to represent morphisms in a fibration in the internal type theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, type-theory, categorical-logic

Given a fibration $p:\mathcal{E \to B}$, we can work with a minimal type theory with semantics in $p:\mathcal{E \to B}$, its internal type theory.

The type theory for $p$ is dependent, with contexts given by objects of $\mathcal{B}$ and objects of $\mathcal{E}$ giving instead dependent types so that for each $E: \mathcal{E}_\Gamma$,where $\Gamma = p(E) : \mathcal{B}$, we can write
$$
\vec x :\Gamma \vdash E(\vec x)\ \text{type}
$$
Morphisms in $\mathcal{B}$ are then substitutions, so that for each $t:\Gamma \to \Delta$ we have rules
$$
\dfrac{\vec y : \Delta \vdash E(\vec y)\ \text{type}}{\vec x :\Gamma \vdash E(\vec y)[\vec y/f(\vec x)]\ \text{type}}
$$
where $[-/-]$ denotes substitution of the first thing with the second thing.

So far so good.

Problem comes when I want to represent a morphism in a fibre of $p$. Say we have $\phi:E \to E'$ over $\Gamma$. I can't write it as
$$
\vec x : \Gamma \vdash \phi(\vec x) : E(\vec x) \to E'(\vec x)
$$
since this is a typing judgment for an arrow type, so an *internal* representation of $\phi$.

My guess is $\phi$ should instead correspond to an admissible rule:
$$
\dfrac{\vec x : \Gamma \vdash e : E(\vec x)}{\vec x : \Gamma \vdash \phi(\vec x, e) : E'(\vec x)}
$$
Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to have a term judgment that has *one* $\mathcal{E}$-variable in the context, in a separate zone from the ambient $\mathcal{B}$-context.  So the judgment

$$ \vec{x} : \Gamma \mid y : E(\vec{x}) \vdash \phi(\vec{x},y) : E'(\vec{x})$$

would represent the morphism you want.  There's an extensive study of these kinds of theories in Valery Isaev's paper [Indexed type theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08038).

Comment: Ah, neat! With this notation Sigma and Pi types get more traditional-looking rules too